# When trying to update my VB.net application, can I just replace it with a new EXE? Or do I have to change all the other files?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

When I have my Visual Studio Express 2013 application, I compile it with Inno Setup (I would use Install Shield but I only have Express). But when I compile it I select every single file in the Project Folder so it includes "WindowsApplication1.exe.config" and other things and all other files. However, I have when I want it to install new updates, do I have to do the config files and all the other ones or can I just replace Application.exe (version 1.0.0.0) with Application.exe (2.0.0.0).

(Also, because when it is compiled, with Inno setup it just creates a Install Wizard, so it installs it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application" will I have to make them download the installer  or just the exe?) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the version in the solution, rebuild. Innosetup just points to the exe - so run Innosetup again and it will be the new version. When the installer runs it detects the older version and will update your app.

Comment: Ahh right, so when they download the Installer from a file sharing site ,they run it and and when there is an update they click update, shoul it download the New Installer and NOT the exe?

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you very much. So I can just do `Process.Start(Installer.exe)`? So it will automatically start the Install Wizard when downloaded? Also, will it automatically overwrite the other updater in future updates, or I will I have to Delete them then make it download?

Comment: It has been awhile since I used Inno, but I think you statement is correct - downloading will overwrite the setup file, no delete.

Comment: I am getting an error saying that it already exists, I think I might have to make it delete the existing Install file and then replace with the new one and run it?

Comment: Testing will always sort out the details =)

Comment: Ahh right, I did a lot of testing, it is more in-depth in a new thread here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456852/getting-error-when-trying-to-update-my-vb-net-project